# Does quartz scheduler support configured jitter to avoid herding effect?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jitter

For example, if you have a lot of jobs scheduled exactly at the same time, it becomes hard to handle.

Comment: Your "question" is not much of a question, more of a statement. The title should be a short summary of your problem, which you detail and *ask about* in the body of the question. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And your answer is not an answer.

Comment: No, it's a *comment*. If I wanted to actually answer I would have written a proper answer below.

Comment: I sometimes search the web, find something really useful and practical. And I click the link, only to find a closed question. If you simply don't have the knowledge to understand the question, why don't you just leave it there and let who are helpful to answer it?

Comment: The question looks OK to me. When you have lots of jobs scheduled to execute at the same time and Quartz does not have enough worker threads to handle the load, you will get so-called trigger misfires. How the Quartz scheduler handles misfires depends on how your triggers are configured. Every Quartz trigger has a misfire instruction that you can configure when you create the trigger and the instruction tells the scheduler what to do. I recommend that you read this blog post for details: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html

Comment: @janMoravec Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: +1 to this question. An additional problem I'm dealing with on my end is that these jobs are being run on multiple Kubernetes pods, which means that a single instance of the scheduler does not have visibility of the herding effect.